# How to get a file from an S3 bucket then send it over email using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, mime

I've been working on a service where I must grab a csv file from an S3 bucket, then send it all using python. I've tried various different methods such as MIMEapplication, however all have encountered problems : (

I think the biggest issue is that most examples define a path to a local directory, opposed to accessing the file through s3, so any help would be appreciated !!!

Comment: Did you check boto3 already? It offers quite a few functions to engage with S3: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html

Answer (score 2):

You would first need to download the file from the Amazon S3 bucket to the local disk.

For example:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('my-bucket', 'object-name', '/tmp/filename')
```

Alternatively, you might be able to use [smart-open · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/), which gives the ability to `open()` a file in Amazon S3 as if it were on a local disk.

Comment: If you were to try and download the file to the local disk, what sort of code would you write? I've been trying to do it this way but I think I get mixed up in terms of naming conventions like object name, file name, etc. when loading in parameters

Comment: See: [Downloading files — Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html)

Comment: I've tried using the code:

 import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME')

however I usually get an error when it comes to FILE_NAME : ( could you provide an example of a sort of path that you would use here ? sorry

Comment: I have added an example. The filename is the local name of where to save the file (including the path). Or, if you're on Windows, then the filename could be: `C:\temp\filename.txt`